# Karate: Is there a way to have setup for each scenario outline

Tags: karate, bdd

I am currently exploring karate framework. For scenario outline, trying to read a file in setup() , pass the data to Examples section and then use data in Scenario outline. Each scenario require data from different file: Ex: scenario 1 -> test1.csv    scenario 2-> test2.csv. I have tried using setup() for each scenario outline as below but both scenarios reading data from first setup().
Is there a way to achieve this. Please let me know.

```
Feature: Test scenarios

@setup
Scenario:
* def data = read('test1.csv')  # reading this file which is required in scenario outline - first scenario

Scenario Outline: first scenario
* print __row


Examples:
    | karate.setup().data |


@setup
Scenario: 
* def data = read('test2.csv')   # reading this file which is required in scneario outline - second scenario

Scenario Outline: second scenario
* print __row


Examples:
    | karate.setup().data |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, read the documentation: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#setup

You can give names to the `@setup`:

```
Feature:

@setup=myname
Scenario:
* def data = [{ a: 1 }, { a: 2}]

Scenario Outline:
* print __row

Examples:
| karate.setup('myname').data |
```

That said, my suggestion is don't over-complicate things when you start out with Karate. Just use separate feature files.

Comment: Thank you Peter for quick response. The above mentioned solution helped my requirement.