# Performing CRUD Operations on Leads Using Karate: Creating, Retrieving, and Updating with CSV Data

Tags: karate, karate-call-single

I am working on an API testing project using Karate for CRUD operations on leads. Specifically, I need to create leads from CSV data(meaning i am converting csv data into JSON request using JSON placeholders), retrieve the created lead, extract important information for updates, update leads using another CSV file(meaning i will place important fields fetched from get into JSON request and other data fields from csv), and finally retrieve the updated lead data.

Specific Questions:
How can I ensure that when the feature is executing, the first row of the CSV used for creating data, and also first row of csv should be used for updating data in Karate?

This whole thing is a workflow so how can i ensure that everything work in flow, creating data from csv using scenario outline, getting the data, and updating data from csv using scenario outline and then again getting updated data?

Comment: you are trying to do too much with some csv structure you have in mind. maybe you will have some luck with the `@setup` annotation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75319233/143475 - else please assume that karate is the wrong tool for what you are trying to do. all the best

Comment: @PeterThomas i wanted this whole process as a workflow , where i can use csv in create and update , meaning first row data used in create request, then get the data using get request and then using some important fields from get and using it with first data from update csv in update request and then fetch the updated data by get request. then similar process for second row of both csv and so on. till the create csv is completed.

Comment: that's what I said. if you are expecting different behavior for each row of the csv, then you have to write some code and karate is not for you. if you want to do the same "workflow" for each row, then just use a `Scenario Outline` and there are plenty of examples and documentation: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#dynamic-scenario-outline